# Git - Private Multi-repo ticket/issue system

Tags: git, system-administration

I'm working on a personal project and keeping tracks of my dev using a simple git-ssh solution to store my repos on a shared server.

Having multiple repos, is there a way to have a single ticket/issue system and to browse source code. I have tried git-web, but I'm not sure I could use it for multiple repos. Some idea about single ticket system for multiple repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bugzilla supports multiple projects and multiple components in each project.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a git-based ticket tracking system like [ticgit](https://github.com/jeffWelling/ticgit), and have it either shared between all of your repositories, or just put it in it's own separate repository that you manage along with your others.